# tensorflow/keras does not load model file right on apache2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mod-wsgi

what do I have:

windows 10 x64, anaconda3(python 3.6.4), apache2.4, mod_wsgi, flask webapp

what do I want:

deploy flask web on apache with mod_wsgi, flask web use scikit-learn and tensorflow/keras models

what I tried:

1. open a command prompt and **activate tf15**, **python runserver.py**

   ```
   from myFlaskApp import app
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run('localhost', 8081)
   ```

   everything works
2. open a command prompt and **activate tf15**, **mod_wsgi-express module-config**

I have added this in apache httpd.conf

```
LoadFile "c:/anaconda3/envs/tf15/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/anaconda3/envs/tf15/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/anaconda3/envs/tf15"
```

everything works, the home page shows, **sklearn models works** but not TF keras.models.load_model("path_to_model_file.h5")
throws exception: The Session graph is empty

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     self.model = K.models.load_model(modelFilePath)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\models.py", line 246, in load_model\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\topology.py", line 3166, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\backend\\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2370, in batch_set_value\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\client\\session.py", line 895, in run\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     run_metadata_ptr)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\client\\session.py", line 1055, in _run\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579] RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579] \r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     self.model = K.models.load_model(modelFilePath)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\models.py", line 246, in load_model\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\topology.py", line 3166, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\backend\\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2370, in batch_set_value\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\client\\session.py", line 895, in run\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     run_metadata_ptr)\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]   File "c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf15\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\client\\session.py", line 1055, in _run\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579]     raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '\r
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579] RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
[wsgi:error] [pid 7108:tid 1404] [client ::1:55579] \r
```

I'm pretty sure it is not empty, and the model file exist because it works when flask host it

what I missed ? grateful for any idea

Comment: Some of the numpy, scipy and related maths packages do not work if run in a Python sub interpreter. I am not sure if tensorflow is the same, but are you setting ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`` in your Apache configuration. That solves the problem for the other libraries.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton just tried add WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , sorry I hit Enter , 
restart apache service , got the same exception.  then tried sth else : stop the service and start server by cmd      "c:\apache24\bin\httpd"  , it just worked. I think we are getting closer.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton  tried nginx/uwsgi on redhat7 without venv or anaconda, just one compiled python36 env,  the web pages work fine, pymssql works fine, but keras.models.load_model(modelFilePath) got timeout. I'm desperate